# How to send post Object with retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit2

i have trouble sending a post request to my API. i need to send the data in a form like this

```
userinfo:{  
   Name="sample",
   Company="sample",
   Contact="Contact"
},
Password="",
PasswordConfirm="",
TokenStr=""
}
```

---

Do I need to use `@Body` annotation to send my Request? 
Here is my Sample Code(Updated)

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        User userReg = new User("asd","asd","bryce@email.com","asd",
                "asd","asd","asd","1");
        UserRegistration sendReg = new UserRegistration(userReg,"asd","asd",
                token);
        final Call<UserRegistration> tableCall = apiService.getUserRegistration(sendReg);
        tableCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserRegistration>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserRegistration> call, Response<UserRegistration> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.e("asdasd",response.body().toString());
                }else{
                    Log.e("asdas",response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserRegistration> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR",""+t.getMessage()+" "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

---

and here is my ApiInterface(updated)

```
@POST("UserRegistration")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<UserRegistration> getUserRegistration(@Body UserRegistration userRegistration);
```

---

I've added a Model Class

```
public class UserRegistration {

    User items;
    String Password;
    String PasswordConfirm;
    String TokenStr;

    public UserRegistration(User items, String password, String passwordConfirm, String tokenStr) {
        this.items = items;
        Password = password;
        PasswordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
        TokenStr = tokenStr;
    }
}

public class User {

    private String COMPANY;
    private String CONTACT_NO;
    private String EMAIL;
    private String FNAME;
    private String LNAME;
    private String MI;
    private String POSITION;
    private String RID;

    public User(String COMPANY, String CONTACT_NO, String EMAIL, String FNAME, String LNAME, String MI, String POSITION, String RID) {
        this.COMPANY = COMPANY;
        this.CONTACT_NO = CONTACT_NO;
        this.EMAIL = EMAIL;
        this.FNAME = FNAME;
        this.LNAME = LNAME;
        this.MI = MI;
        this.POSITION = POSITION;
        this.RID = RID;
    }
}
```

Now I get an error saying @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1).

But i receive bad request. i know that my request is wrong. and im new to android. I tried to research on how to do this but I didnt find any helpful answers.

Comment: try to send using jsonObject or create a model and pass data in the request body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The JSON you provided is little wrong,correct it
2. Make A POJO according to your JSON
3. Change the `getUserRegistration()` In `ApiInterface` to

@POST("account/verify")

Call register(@Body RegisterRequest registerRequest)

You can refer to this article : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: I've tried what you said but I get a new error @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1). I updated my question

Comment: remove @FormUrlEncoded annotation and try again..Why don't you go through the the article I referred

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use @Body like this:
2. @POST
       Call getUserRegistration(@Body Userinfo userinfo);
3. Make a model for your json and pass it as the parameter.

Comment: New Error occured @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1). Do I need to use multi or hash here?